# Unexplainable call to class constructor generates "matching function error"

Tags: c++

When I call merge_sort I get a string of errors as such the most readable is:

```
no matching function call to dynamic_array<int>::dynamic_array()
```

Does having a base class instantiate a sub class cause that sub-class to re-instantiate the calling base class?

This was my first guess.

// Calling main function

```
#include "c_dynamic_array.cpp"
int main()
  {
  dynamic_array<int> d1(20);
  d1.order();cout << d1 << endl;
  d1.rorder();cout << d1 << endl;
  d1.randorder();cout << d1 << endl;
  d1.merge_sort();cout << d1 << endl; // This line starts a string of errors
  }
```

// Dynamic Array Class and Merge Inner (merge sort) Class

```
#include "c_include.cpp"

/*
Dynamic Array
*/

using namespace std;
template <typename> class merge_inner;

template <class T> class dynamic_array
  {
  protected:
    T* array;
  public:
    int size;
    void rorder();
    void order();
    void randorder();
    void print_operator(ostream&)const;
    dynamic_array(int sizein)
      {
      size=sizein;
      array=new T[size]();
      }
    void merge_sort()
      {
      merge_inner<T> M1;
      }
  };
template <class T> void dynamic_array<T>::print_operator(ostream &os=cout)const
  {
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) os << array[i] << endl;
  }
template <class T> void dynamic_array<T>::randorder()
  {
  srand(time(NULL));
  int *ap;
  for(ap=array;ap!=array+size;++ap){*ap=rand()%size;} 
  }
template <class T> void dynamic_array<T>::order()
  {
  int *ap,i=0;
  for(ap=array;ap!=array+size;++ap)                                             
    { 
    *ap=i;
    ++i;        
    } 
  }
template <class T> void dynamic_array<T>::rorder()
  {
  int *ap,i=size-1;
  for(ap=array;ap!=array+size;++ap)                                             
    { 
    *ap=i;
    --i;        
    } 
  }
template<class T> ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, dynamic_array<T> const& data) 
  { 
  data.print_operator(stream);
  return stream; 
  }   

/*
Merge Sort
*/

template <class T> class merge_inner : public dynamic_array <T>
  {
  using dynamic_array<T>::array;
  private:
    const static int size;
    T *scratch;
    void flip_if_unordered(int &x, int &y)
      {
      if(array[x]>array[y])
        {
        int tmp=array[x];
        array[x]=array[y];
        array[y]=tmp;
        }
      }
    void merge_algo(int &left, int &right_begin, int &right)
      {
      int iter,iter_left=left,iter_right=right_begin;  
      for(iter=left;iter<=right;++iter)
        {
        if( (iter_right>right) || ((iter_left < right_begin) && (array[iter_left]<=array[iter_right])))
          {
          scratch[iter]=array[iter_left];
          ++iter_left;
          }
        else
          {
          scratch[iter]=array[iter_right];
          ++iter_right;
          }
        }
      for(iter=left;iter<=right;++iter){array[iter]=scratch[iter];}
      }
    void merge_recurse(int left,int right)
      {
      int left_end=(left+((right-left)/2)); 
      int right_begin=left_end+1;  
      if(((left+1)==right)){flip_if_unordered(left,right);return;}
      else if ((left==right)){return;}
      else
        { 
        merge_recurse(left,left_end);               
        merge_recurse(right_begin,right);  
        merge_algo(left,right_begin,right);
        }   
      }
  public:
    merge_inner()
      {
      scratch = new T[size]();
      if(scratch != NULL){merge_recurse(0, size);}
      }
  };
/*Quick Sort
    void quick_sort()
      {
      quick_recurse(0,size);
      }
    void quick_recurse(int left, int right) 
      {  
      int l = left, r = right, tmp;
      int pivot = array[(left + right) / 2];
      while (l <= r)
        {
        while (array[l] < pivot)l++;
        while (array[r] > pivot)r--;
        if (l <= r) 
          {
          tmp = array[l];
          array[l] = array[r];
          array[r] = tmp;
          l++;
          r--;
          }
        }
      if (left < r)quick_recurse(left, r);
      if (l < right)quick_recurse(l, right);
      }  
*/
```

Comment: `void flip_if_unordered(int &x, int &y)` <-- You don't want to do that since you are not modifying the arguments. That will prevent your function from being called with literals like `flip_if_uinordered(0,1)`. You could change it to `int const&` but its less efficient than passing by value (simply `int`).

Comment: I thought passing by reference took up less space b.c. it does not create a copy of the values passed.  It should be more space efficient..that is why I used it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dynamic_array` seems to be missing a default constructor, and since it has a custom constructor the compiler will not provide one. Add this to your class:

```
  dynamic_array()
  {
      size = 0;
      array = new T[0](); // or NULL, but note that new T[0] will be != NULL
  }
```

Alternatively, provide a default `sizein` for your existing constructor so that it can be used as a default constructor as well:

```
dynamic_array(int sizein = 0)
```

Comment: OK...now I'm getting undefined reference to  merge_inner<int>::size...there is no line number...how can I pipe the error to a text file...in MinGW I used 2>....but now I'm using DOS command and > does not work...

Comment: OK I took size out of merge_inner...now I'm  having the same problem I had earlier that you told me to use the using statement

Comment: @Chris Aaker: You have declared `const static int size;` but you don't define it anywhere. It doesn't look like it should be `static`, but if it does then you need something like `template< typename T > const int inner_merge<T>::size = ?;` outside the class body.

Comment: Do I add another using statement...the whole purpose of having a sub-class was to automatically inherit this property...why is it not happeing?

Comment: @Chris Aaker: Because your base class is dependent on a template argument. So the members are inherited, but they are not visible to the compiler. You need to be explicit about it (with `using`) when inheriting from a dependent type.

Comment: Inherited but not visible...got it...won't forget it...thanks again

Comment: Normally I would want to know why...but C++ has owned me today..and I'm not curious any more..Thanks...

Comment: @Chris Aaker: Simply because the compiler can't inspect the contents of your base class to see if something is a member or not (due to being dependent on a template type, the actual base will only be known at instantiation time). You ask the compiler to trust you that it is an inherited member, and to give an error if it isn't.

Comment: OK one last question::How many times does my base class dynamic_array get instantiated?  Once or twice...obviously when I create it in main..but when I call merge_sort..does it instantiate another object?

Comment: It'd suffice to add the subobject constructor to the base initializer list of the `merge_inner` constructor.

Comment: @Chris Aaker: Your linker error seems to suggest that its instantiated in more places than just `main`. Place a breakpoint in its constructors and debug the application to see exactly when its called.

Comment: @Kerrek BS: Adding `dynamic_array<T>()` to `merge_inner`'s initialization list would suffice to make all its members visible? I don't see how that would work, the compiler does not know the actual specialization (if any) that is used as a base until it instantiates the whole thing.

Comment: @K-ballo: Hm, no... let me back up: 1) `dynamic_array<T>` doesn't have a default constructor. 2) merge_inner<T> derives from `dynamic_array<T>`. 3) the derived constructor must construct the base subobject: `merge_inner<T>::merge_inner() : dynamic_array<T>(0) { }`

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Oh yeah, you are correct. Sorry the comment discussion went for too long I forgot about the original question/answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since your base class `dynamic_array<T>` doesn't have a default constructor, every derived class constructor must call some base constructor one way or another. Put the base initialization in the constructor initializer list. For example:

```
template <typename T>
class merge_inner : public dynamic_array<T>
{
public:
  merge_inner() : dynamic_array<T>(0) { }
  // ...
};
```